# black screen with cursor after login recurs the second boot after single user mode fix

Tags: startup, mac-pro

Trying to upgrade a MacPro5,1 (2010) to an SSD, I installed High Sierra in it from a 2010 Macbook pro via USB, because it was too damn slow to install it directly in the MacPro, then put the SSD in the MacPro.

At first it worked fine, but after a few hours every time i started it, it went into a black screen after introducing login credentials. Mouse still visible and movable. Cmd+Option+Esc sequence for force quit applications would show up, with an empty list (no Finder even). Pressing the power button would make the power menu appear, but none of the buttons work. I got it to finally work at some point, but I have no idea how, my brain was fried at the moment - maybe it was a matter of waiting for a really long time.

Anyway, I went through all the remedies found online. Booting into Single User Mode to delete the com.apple.loginwindow.plist file worked - but only for one boot. The next time, it would be black screen again. The same pattern repeated with applying an update, or even going to recovery mode and reinstalling the system. First boot, fine, after that we go into black screen.

I'm assuming something I did after installing the system is corrupting that preference file after every boot, but most of the stuff I did was pretty vanilla, just installed a handful of applications and setup the mail client. This is not my computer so when I go to try to fix it again I'd like to know what other things I should be on the lookout for - specific log files?
Could the installing it from another computer be the problem?Some kind of firmware mismatch?

Comment: After any hardware change, it's always wise to reset the SMC. Also, what GPU does it have & what OS was on it before High Sierra? Try re-installing the OS, in situ, from the Recovery Partition & make sure you're on the latest High Sierra 10.13.6 https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1970

Comment: GPU is ATI Radeon HD 5770. Former OS can't check at the moment right now unfortunately, but definitely pre-sierra. I tried already reinstalling from the recovery partition and it's on 10.13.6. I can't check anything else until i go there in a couple days...will update if i find out

Comment: oh my, just figured out that it boots up just fine as long as the old hard drive with the old system is also connected!

Comment: That's bizarre! You mean it boots to the new drive so long as the old one is also there [just to clarify]? I've never known that ever to happen - it's not like Windows where the boot instructions can be on one drive but the OS on another, Macs boot from 'rom' in effect. Make sure the new drive has a Recovery partition [with the right OS on it] & run an OS install from Recovery. That should paper over any cracks without deleting any data.

Comment: In the end, it fixed itself, and I still have no idea what caused it.